# Fetching data from database in a loop

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Is there a logical way to get the data from sql periodically? I want to fetch a row from a table in my postgres DB, run some calculations on it in my python script, and fetch the second row of the data and go on with this procedure till all the calculation has been done.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDsUJ.png)

In the table above, I would like to fetch each array of the travel time, do the calculations on it in my python code, and then go to the 2nd row and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your database library will provide you with a method for doing this. It might be called a cursor, a pointer or an iterator, which will have a method for fetching the next row from a query.

From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM employees")
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row is not None:
  print(row)
  row = cursor.fetchone()
```